# DSpace as Library Management System

Tags: dspace

Is it possible DSpace works, beyond the known features, as a Library Management System for a not virtual library, i.e. manage picked up books, etc.

I cant found any extension/plugin providing this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managing loans etc of physical objects is not a part of the DSpace feature set. If you're after an Open Source system that can provide this functionality, perhaps have a look at [Koha](https://koha-community.org/).